# How can I Connect orientDB to angularJS web application

Tags: angularjs, database, angular, orientdb, nosql

I need to connect orientDB with my angularJS login web application.
after log in user allowed to iput some data to web application and those data also need to be stored in the orient DB data base .
So i need to connect database with my angularJS web application and to use database to store and retrieve data,

Comment: What did you do so far? Your question does not show any effort and is too general.

Comment: @cccross i created the web app using angularJs ( without controller ) ,this is the first time I'm trying nosql database and its bit difficult to me. And i created the database and vertex 
(I'm new to both angularJs and orientDB)

Comment: Take inspiration from this one: https://github.com/gauravdhiman/sailsjs-angularjs-orientdb-poc

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample Angular2 service to connect to OrientDB

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class OrientService {

  url = "http://localhost:2480/command/yourDbName/"
  username = "admin";
  password = "admin";

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  command(statement: string, success: (data: any) => void, error: (err: any) => void): void {
    var url = this.url + "sql/-/-1"
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(this.username + ":" +     this.password));

    this.http.post(url,
      JSON.stringify({"command": statement}),
      {headers: headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(success)
      .catch(error);
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
 this.orientService.command(
       "SELECT FROM V",
       (res) => {
         let body = res.json();
         ...
       },
       (e) => {
         console.log(e)
       });
```

Here you can find a full example: https://github.com/luigidellaquila/geospatial-demo/tree/geeconprague2016

Consider that you will have to enable cross-site requests in OrientDB https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Web-Server.html